# ¿Qué tan válido es el doble posesivo?

Tags: gramática, posesivos

En los últimos días, empecé a leer la novela de [José Rizal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Rizal) [Noli me tangere](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noli_me_tangere_(novela)), y en el capítulo IV noté que un personaje le comenta al otro las siguientes frases:

> (...)su padre, de Ud., que estaba preso! (...) (sic.)
>
> (...)Los Españoles que venimos a Filipinas no somos desgraciadamente lo que debíamos: digo esto tanto por uno de sus abuelos de Ud. (...) (sic.)
>
> (...)Meses después de su salida de Ud. (...) (sic.)

Aunque la obra es de finales del siglo XIX y en español filipino, me llama la atención la segunda frase, en la que al personaje que habla se le atribuye un origen español, y alguna vez en una obra de Les Luthiers lo había oído (La comisión), al ser esta una obra cómica lo suponía como broma, pero entonces ¿aclaraciones tipo *suyo de usted* o *su cosa de usted* son válidas?

Comment: Quizás no entendí bien la pregunta.  Yo pensaría que el personaje iba a decir, "Su padre que estaba preso" pero como podría ser ambiguo a quién se refiere "su", por eso se agregó "de usted".

Comment: Al menos en mi país (México) es muy común el doble posesivo en el habla. Casi siempre tienen la forma «su + sustantivo + de». De hecho, casi nadie parece preguntarse si es una construcción correcta o no. Recuerdo incluso que mis profesores de lengua solían hablar en ocasiones así. No sé si sea algo regional entonces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He visto ese tipo de frases sobre todo en textos antiguos. Si buscamos en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) **«su padre de usted»**, por poner un ejemplo, nos devuelve más de 50 resultados, la mayoría del siglo XIX y algunos del XX.

> ¿Se ha quedado su padre de usted en León?
>
> Y su padre de usted, ¿cómo está?
>
> (...) voy á buscar á su padre de usted para decirle (...)

Por otra parte según este [artículo](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Su%20-%20de%20usted.htm) de Hispanoteca también se usa en el habla moderna aunque no creo que sea muy común, al menos en España. En ese artículo explica que se utiliza para evitar la ambigüedad del posesivo *su*:

> Para remediar la indeterminación del poseedor, nuestro idioma se vale, desde antes de la época clásica, del recurso de añadir a *su, sus* el nombre del poseedor, o el pronombre que lo señala, precedido por la preposición *de*, siempre que el contexto no basta para indicarlo: *su casa de Antonio; sus rentas de usted; su madre de ellas.*

Comment: Este tipo de usos lo he visto en el español clasico, y tambien un poco en el conteporaneo en casos de extrema formalidad.

Answer (score 6):

Como el adjetivo posesivo ***su*** es ambiguo, en ocaciones es necesario especificar el *poseedor*. La partícula ***de*** es una preposición de pertenencia, la cual califica al adjetivo y así se elimina la ambiguedad.

En los 50's y 60's, esta expresión era común en el Español Tapatio (Guadalajara, Mexico), con el cual yo crecí. Se enseñaba en la escuela primaria con tablas como la siguiente:

- su de él - su automovil de él
- su de ella - su bolso de ella
- su de ellos - su casa de ellos
- su de ellas - su escuela de ellas

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta sin duda.

Answer (score 3):

Se usa coloquialmente en México. "Su casa de Pepe es muy bonita ", en lugar de "la casa..." Y también en la situación presentada en la pregunta, donde se intenta evitar dudas de la relación entre parientes.

En mi experiencia, se interpreta como señal de que el que habla tiene poca educación, así que lo escuché imitado muchas veces en tono burlón.

Mi impresión (y es sólo mi sensibilidad personal sobre cómo ha evolucionado el español en México) es que la connotación de baja educación en este caso está correlacionada con que fuese expresión de uso común hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: En un comentario a la pregunta, se da como *muy común* en México, quizá a un nivel regional o rural (sin querer entrar en dilemas socio culturales)

Comment: No sólo es particular de México, en Perú, Bolivia, Chile y Ecuador también es ampliamente usado el doble posesivo. Expresiones tales como: *Vamos a su casa de ella* o *Sus hijos de él* son muy comunes en estos países.

Answer (score 1):

Sin descartar la posibilidad de que exista como forma dialectal, yo lo leí, incluso a la segunda y tercera vez, como si hubiese dos comas, con las cuales lo de «de usted» sirve para aclarar:

> … su padre, <sub>(es decir el)</sub> de usted, que estaba preso …

Voy a intentar investigarlo algo más.  Los posesivos varían algo en lo que admiten en distintas partes del mundo hispanohablante, y lo dicho, puede ser así una forma plenamente válida en el español filipino o en otra parte, aunque de momento la ignoro como tal.

Comment: agrego un par de ejemplos del mismo corte en el capítulo, que pueden dar una mayor claridad